# How can I migrate my Xfce configuration and settings to another system?

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

I want to replicate my current Xfce configuration complete with *all* settings on another Debian installation.

What file(s) do I need to copy and keep track of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to [What to save before re-installing?](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7432), duplicating your

```
~/.config/xfce4
```

folder should do the trick.

In any case, all your user configuration is in your home folder.